# How to install source jar to Nexus?

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have the jar file (.class files) of an external library that I need in my project and is not found on public repo, so I have installed it to Nexus in my company via its admin interface, all working good.

What is missing is the source code. I have a seperate source jar (.java files) of that external library, do I simply install it to Nexus via its admin interface the same? I did not see anywhere that specify its a source code jar in the UI, except the file name has -source in it. Thank you.

Comment: in the upload screen specify the classifier as "source".

Comment: @Henry Thank you! Do I also have to name the file with the -source suffix together with this classifier?

Comment: No, the file name is irrelevant. The file will get a new name based on the module, classifier, and version settings.